# Python script not entering for loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, raspberry-pi

I'm writing a script from a tutorial I found online that essentially just reads the news. The script now compiles and launches, but doesn't actually do anything. After debugging, I found that it doesn't enter into the for-loop, and I'm not sure why.

```
import subprocess
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import textwrap

head = 'mpg123 -q '
tail = ' &'

url = 'http://www.ndtv.com/article/list/top-stories/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

print '1'

g_data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"natory_intro"})
log = open("/home/pi/logs/newslog.txt","w")
for item in g_data:
    print '2'
    #print >> log, item.text
    shorts = textwrap.wrap(item.text, 100)
    print '3'

    for sentance in shorts:
            print '4'
            sendthis = sentance.join(['"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?t1=en&q=', '"'])
            print[head + sendthis + tail]
            #print subprocess.call(head + sendthis + tail, shell=True)
            print subprocess.check_output (head + sendthis + tail, shell=True)
            print '5'
```

`g_data` was loaded with the data from the website, so there is an item in `g_data`, but it still doesn't get caught in the loop. It's probably a really simple fix, but I just can't see it right now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So which `print` statements do you see, and which aren't reached?

Comment: Maybe g_data is not iterable?! Can you check your g_data type?

Comment: Where are you getting `natory_intro` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo on this line

```
g_data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"natory_intro"})
```

Should be

```
g_data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"nstory_intro"})
```

Comment: Ahhh just a small typo, of course that was my problem. It works now, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't enter the loop because `g_data` is an empty list.

Check the website, make sure you can get items by class name `"natory_intro"`.

I run:

```
import subprocess
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import textwrap

head = 'mpg123 -q '
tail = ' &'

url = 'http://www.ndtv.com/article/list/top-stories/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"natory_intro"})
print g_data
```

I get

```
[]
```

Edit:

I guess this is what you want:

```
#ins_storylist > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div.new_storylising_contentwrap > div.nstory_intro
```

Just change `"natory_intro"` to `"nstory_intro"`.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. Should I delete the answer?